# wall post on facebook from hybrid mobile application

Tags: facebook, hybrid-mobile-app

I am having a hybrid mobile application(should work in android and ios). In which I need to post on facebook wall from my application. Please note its a hybrib app, so I am not supposed to use any java or c code.

I tried the following method , its working in simulator , but not in actual device. Please help me.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : ' my appID',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});
};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').live('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'HyperArts Blog',
link: 'http://hyperarts.com/blog',
picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/_img/TabPress-LOGO-Home.png',
caption: 'I love HyperArts tutorials',
description: 'The HyperArts Blog provides tutorials for all things Facebook',
message: ''
});
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this. your:
    document.location.protocol
which is suppose to pull in the FB SDK is actually "file:///" and thats what gets fed into the  url for that FB JS library.
Manually specify http:// or https://
This didnt work for me either on safari webView on IOS so i had to hit the endpoints manually using AJAX.

Comment: You have an example how to do it? Thanks.